# Apply set of operation on one entire column in unix file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I have a file looks like :

```
    "JOB1 #43",  43 "SUCCESS",  1479079800029
    "JOB1 #42",  42 "SUCCESS",  1478993400042
    "JOB1 #41",  41 "SUCCESS",  1478907000065
    "JOB1 #40",  40 "SUCCESS",  1478820600085
    "JOB1 #39",  39 "SUCCESS",  1478734200051
```

need to change last column (timestamp) with date and time format.

Tried so far :

```
 for i in `cat file | awk '{print $NF}'`
 do
      date -d @$(  echo "(${i} + 500) / 1000" | bc)
 done
```

Output:

```
    Sun Nov 13 23:30:00 GMT 2016
    Sat Nov 12 23:30:00 GMT 2016
    Fri Nov 11 23:30:00 GMT 2016
    Thu Nov 10 23:30:00 GMT 2016
    Wed Nov  9 23:30:00 GMT 2016
```

Expected output is

```
"JOB1 #43",  43 "SUCCESS",  Sun Nov 13 23:30:00 GMT 2016
"JOB1 #42",  42 "SUCCESS",  Sat Nov 12 23:30:00 GMT 2016
"JOB1 #41",  41 "SUCCESS",  Fri Nov 11 23:30:00 GMT 2016
"JOB1 #40",  40 "SUCCESS",  Thu Nov 10 23:30:00 GMT 2016
"JOB1 #39",  39 "SUCCESS",  Wed Nov  9 23:30:00 GMT 2016
```

Can we change it in file itself?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `awk` can read files, no need for `cat`: `awk '{print $NF}' file`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
awk -F',\\s*' '{print $1 "," $2 "," strftime("%c", $3/1000)}' file
```

Outputs:

```
"JOB1 #43",43 "SUCCESS",Sun 13 Nov 2016 23:30:00 GMT
"JOB1 #42",42 "SUCCESS",Sat 12 Nov 2016 23:30:00 GMT
"JOB1 #41",41 "SUCCESS",Fri 11 Nov 2016 23:30:00 GMT
"JOB1 #40",40 "SUCCESS",Thu 10 Nov 2016 23:30:00 GMT
"JOB1 #39",39 "SUCCESS",Wed 09 Nov 2016 23:30:00 GMT
```

You may like to adjust the date format as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this awk command (will work with non-gnu awk as well):

```
awk -F , '{cmd="TZ=UTC date -d @" sprintf("%d", ($NF+500)/1000); 
           cmd | getline dt; gsub(/[0-9]+$/, dt); close(cmd)} 1' file

"JOB1 #43",  43 "SUCCESS",  Sun Nov 13 23:30:00 UTC 2016
"JOB1 #42",  42 "SUCCESS",  Sat Nov 12 23:30:00 UTC 2016
"JOB1 #41",  41 "SUCCESS",  Fri Nov 11 23:30:00 UTC 2016
"JOB1 #40",  40 "SUCCESS",  Thu Nov 10 23:30:00 UTC 2016
"JOB1 #39",  39 "SUCCESS",  Wed Nov  9 23:30:00 UTC 2016
```

- We use `getline` function to call your desired `date` command and store output in variable `dt`
- Finally wee use `gsub` instead of assignment i.e. `$NF = dt` to maintain formatting of input record in output

Comment: I was applying the same on large file:::
getting error :::
awk: (FILENAME=file FNR=1085) fatal: cannot open pipe `TZ=UTC date -d @1462108027' (Too many open files)

Comment: Oh ok, you can use `awk -F , '{cmd="TZ=UTC date -d @" sprintf("%d", ($NF+500)/1000); cmd | getline dt; gsub(/[0-9]+$/, dt); close(cmd)} 1' file` as that will close each command description in the end.

Answer (score 0):

As you already got the content to replace with, the merging can easily be done using python script.

```
f1=open("a.txt")
f2=open("b.txt")

lines1 = f1.readlines()
lines2 = f2.readlines()
output_lines=[]
for (l1,l2) in zip(lines1,lines2):
   fields = l1.split(",")
   fields[2] = l2
   output_line = ",".join(fields)
   output_lines.append(output_line)
f3 = open("result.txt","w")
f3.writelines(output_lines)
f3.close()
```

output : result.txt

```
"JOB1 #43",  43 "SUCCESS",Sun Nov 13 23:30:00 GMT 2016
"JOB1 #42",  42 "SUCCESS",Sat Nov 12 23:30:00 GMT 2016
"JOB1 #41",  41 "SUCCESS",Fri Nov 11 23:30:00 GMT 2016
"JOB1 #40",  40 "SUCCESS",Thu Nov 10 23:30:00 GMT 2016
"JOB1 #39",  39 "SUCCESS",Wed Nov  9 23:30:00 GMT 2016
```